# How to include all results of a subquery into a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to include the results of a sub-query into my SELECT statement BUT I am stuck on how to do that with my SQL statement. When the sub-query returns one result my statement seem to work fine but when more it returns more than one row it becomes a problem. Below is how my SQL statement is structured:

```
function get_client ($client_ec_no){
    include 'connection.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT cs.*, 
            (SELECT ss.s_name 
                    FROM ss, mcs 
                    WHERE mcs.mcs_s_id = ss.s_id 
                    AND mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ?)

    FROM cs, ss, mcs
    WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?';

    try {
        $results = $db->prepare($sql);
        $results->bindValue(1, $client_ec_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $results->bindValue(2, $client_ec_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        return false;
    }
    return $results->fetch();
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns
>   more than 1 row

Comment: What is the content of `$client_cs_no`?

Comment: The error message says it all. What do you want? Do a LEFT JOIN instead. BTW, your query seems to miss some join conditions.

Comment: where are join conditions for `cs, ss, mcs` in the outer query? You have a cartesian product there!

Comment: @OptimusCrime it's a one-word string

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` it, instead of using it in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT cs.*, t.*
  FROM cs, ss, mcs
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ss.s_name, ss.s_id
    FROM ss, mcs 
    WHERE mcs.mcs_s_id = ss.s_id 
      AND mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ?
) AS t ON ss.s_id = t.s_id AND mcs.mcs_s_id = t.mcs_s_id
  WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?
```

Note that, the tables `FROM cs, ss, mcs` will be `CROSS JOIN` as you didn't supply a join condition. You should add a join condition, and I recommend using the following syntax:

```
SELECT cs.*, t.*
FROM cs
INNER JOIN ss  ON ...
INNER JOIN mcs ON ...
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ss.s_name, ss.s_id
    FROM ss, mcs 
    WHERE mcs.mcs_s_id = ss.s_id 
      AND mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ?
) AS t ON ss.s_id = t.s_id AND mcs.mcs_s_id = t.mcs_s_id
  WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?
```

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes I know it is another way, but where is the join condition for the three tables `cs, ss, mcs` I can see only `WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?` which will filter only on this column, but still will be cross join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The JOIN to solve this error.the following query may use for u.

```
  SELECT cs.*, ss.s_name  FROM ss JOIN mcs ON ss.s_id =  mcs.mcs_s_id  JOIN cs ON cs.client_ec_no = mcs.mcs_client_ec_no WHERE  cs.client_ec_no =?
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood your query like this,
You need all contents from cs table, s_name from ss table. 
And s_id is common in mcs and ss . client_ec_no provided which is present in mcs and cs. Now all three tables are joined.
I restructured your query and added a distinct to that so that there is no duplicates. And also there will be cross join because you did not specify any join conditions in the outer query.

```
  'SELECT distinct cs.*, ss.s_name 
       FROM cs, ss, mcs
      WHERE mcs.mcs_s_id = ss.s_id 
        AND mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ?
        AND cs.client_ec_no = ?'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what your query is meant to do, but if exactly one result in the sub-query is fine, then this will get rid of the error:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cs.*, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 ss.s_name 
         FROM ss LEFT JOIN mcs ON 
             ss.s_id = mcs.mcs_s_id 
         WHERE
             mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ?
        )
        FROM cs
        WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alias and join. Coreect syntax:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT cs.*, 
        (SELECT ss.s_name 
                FROM ss INNER JOIN mcs ON mcs.mcs_s_id = ss.s_id 
                WHERE 
                mcs.mcs_client_ec_no = ? LIMIT 1) AS some_value

FROM cs
WHERE cs.client_ec_no = ?';
```